# Real-time Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, real-time

Very simply, how can I make binding more responsive.  That is, changing the interface closer to when the view model is changed in the background.

I have a timer-based progress bar that is incredibly jumpy. And I have a touchscreen keyboard that updates the field like hours (exaggeration) later than the key is pressed.

Comment: It's not exactly what you are asking for but wpf has something like PriorityBinding so you can display different value when slow binding is loading in background. There is also DispatchPriority so you can decide how quick UI receive items from dispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the queue priorities of the Dispatcher (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx)). Even if you were to respond faster to a change in the ViewModel (for example by manually updating controls), the rendering itself is done at a lower priority. Thus, I guess it won't make any noticeable difference for you to respond faster since the user won't see it under after the next rendering.

EDIT:
In general, the UI in WPF, even when doing data binding, is very responsive. However, there are some reasons why it can be slow (take a look at the app using the [WPF performance toolkit](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/perf/wpf-perf-tool.aspx)):

- The specific control itself (which is so slow) may be too complicated/bloated. For example, I had a control which loaded a 400kb style file every time it was created. Obviously, this took some time. In my case, the solution was to load the style file in the parent control once.
- The main thread (which generally is your UI thread) does too much processing at a time. You might be blocking the thread with some long-running calculation, which means it has no chance to update the UI. So this calculation should be done in a different thread (BackgroundWorker, ThreadPool thread, ...).
- The entire UI may be too complicated. You might have an extremely deep visual/logical tree or be using large styles/templates with lots of triggers or legacy bitmap effects, etc.

Comment: so your answer is that there is no answer?

Comment: I have a project with nearly 1000+ bindings on a page that are dynamic w.r.t. slider controls and it is very responsive.

Comment: @Jordan Basically yes. Since the rendering is done at a lower priority than data binding and normal priority (this makes sense since the data binding might result in rendering changes), any updates to the data binding won't help (*and it might not be the actual problem with slow response!*). You might want to take a look with a profiler, ex. http://windowsclient.net/wpf/perf/wpf-perf-tool.aspx One more option might be to have a second thread where you have your "slow" window(s).

Answer (score 5):

OK, there are three options you can use when it comes to making UI responsive:

(1). Use asynchronous bindings:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelTextProperty, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

This way the value of `ViewModelTextProperty` will be retrieved asynchronously.

(2). Use `PriorityBinding` - it is similar to the previous option, but additionally it allows you to display something while main binding is executing asynchronously:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
      <PriorityBinding>
          <Binding Path="ViewModelTextProperty" IsAsync="True"/>
          <Binding Path="FastViewModelTextProperty" IsAsync="True"/>
      </PriorityBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Slow bindings are specified on the top and the fast ones in the buttom. That is, in this example, value of `FastViewModelTextProperty` will be displayed first and when value of `ViewModelTextProperty` is ready it will be displayed.

(3). And finally, you can use usual asyncronious programming in your view model (call methods asynchronously, use timers, etc.). And whenever you are ready to display some data, update the UI (set values of bound properties) using Dispatcher:

```
private void OnAsyncOperationCompleted()
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
      // Update the UI
   }));
}
```

Comment: this is the opposite direction I'm wanting go.  I'm wanting the view to respond faster to changes in the view model.  I'm not just wanting the interface to be alive while I'm doing some processing.  I have a timer-based progress bar that is incredibly jumpy.  And I have a touchscreen keyboard that updates the field like hours (exaggeration) later than the key is pressed.